# I have a problem with Web 3 capability and Meta Mask In Front End

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I have designed a user interface on the web page(in *html/java script*) to display my smart contract values.

When other users access the web page through **other browsers**, they will **not be able** to receive Web 3 services due to the lack of a digital wallet. Because they **did not installed the wallet on their web Browser** .How can I put Web 3 services and capabilities in my web page **without the user having to install a wallet**?

The codes I used before are shown below:

```html
this.web3 = new Web3(this.provider);
 //***********
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethereumUrl))
  //****************
new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/' + yourInfuraEndPointKey)
);
//*******************
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
//******
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
```

and a lot of code tested. I can't find any answer here. please one help me.
and this is my last Web3 Connection Code:

```js
/*this codes in head of web page ant totali it work*/
/*but i want to work in browser that dont install metamask*/
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') 
            {
                console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
            }else{
                console.log('MetaMask not installed!');
                alert("Please install Metamsk wallet first, then try again");
         }      
            const accounts = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const account = accounts[0];
            const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
      
      
      
var contractH;
const accountsH = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const accountH = accountsH[0];
const showAccountH = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
web333 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); 
//window.web333 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>"));
var addressH = "0x624/*My Contract Address*/4135E7a";
var abiH =[/*My ABI*/];
contractH = new web333.eth.Contract(abiH, addressH); 


    /*and the other code*/  
      
      
      
</script>
```

and when I Run Web Page in Other Browser I see This Error:[image]

and I Before Check and Test detail about this pages :
[this page information](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts)

[and this page](https://www.codemotion.com/magazine/dev-hub/blockchain-dev/web3-js-ethereum-blockchain-javascript-api/)

[and this page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54871/how-to-use-web3-js-library-in-a-javascript-file-without-using-requireweb3)

[and this page](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3.html)

[and this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/web3-provider)

and every pages that in Stack overflow and other sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have to Use Infura:

```js
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3c68e/*your ID*/301753"));
```

and check this [page](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-setup-your-dapps-to-not-use-metamask-plugin-but-sign-the-transaction-backend-b8cb8808c9ae) and this is [infura](https://infura.io/) web page for creating Project at the first time